# How to render CSS and JS files with Go template

Tags: go

I am trying to include CSS and JS files in my html templates using Go.

Here is my code

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    var mux = http.NewServeMux()
    registerRoutes(mux)
    httpServer := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":3000",
        Handler: mux,
    }
    err := httpServer.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
}
```

`routes.go`

```
package main

import "net/http"

func registerRoutes(mux *http.ServeMux) {
    mux.HandleFunc("/", index)
    mux.HandleFunc("/faq", faq)
}
```

`handlers.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/index.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
}

func faq(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/faq.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
}
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Index</title>
        <link href="../static/stylesheets/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/scripts/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Rendering the HTML works, but it does not include the CSS or JS files. How can I get it to recognise them?

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:** As suggested by @Burak Serdar, I have implemented the following code:

Added this to `handlers.go`

```
func staticHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   // load the file using r.URL.Path, like /static/scripts/index.js"
   path := r.URL.Path
   data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
   if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
   if strings.HasSuffix(path, "js") {
      w.Header().Set("Content-Type","text/javascript")
   } else {
      w.Header().Set("Content-Type","text/css")
   }
   _, err = w.Write(data)
   if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
}
```

Added this to `routes.go`

```
mux.HandleFunc("/static", staticHandler)
```

However, it still does not work.

Perhaps I should note that `static/` and `templates/` are in the same folder, and these share the folder with `main.go` etc.

---

**EDIT2:** It seems like my method may not be the best, and so I am trying to use the inbuilt `FileServer`. However, I can't quite work out how to do it.

I added this line

```
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("C:/Users/x/Documents/Coding/Go/hello_world/"))))
```

to `registerRoutes` but it's not working.

---

**EDIT3:** Perhaps I should make it clear what I am trying to achieve. I am attempting to reach Flask-like functionality in Go. This means redirecting to certain templates based on the path visited. What I mean by a template is a `.html` file that I can pass variables to.

---

**EDIT4:** I think I have achieved what I wanted. I added

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
mux.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static", fs))
```

to my `main()` function in `main.go`. Then removed `mux.HandleFunc("/static/", staticHandler)` and the `staticHandler` function.

---

**EDIT5:** Assuming that is a good method, my last concern is how to handle caching. It is clear that I am parsing the files every time the page is rendered with `tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/index.html")` etc. As such, I thought perhaps I could add a function to load these files and return the templates, then call this function in main and pass the variables to the handlers. Is this a good idea? How would you go about doing it exactly? Does this mean my files only get updated when I restart my web server?

For example

```
func initTemplates() (*template.Template, *template.Template) {
    indexTemplate := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/index.html"))
    faqTemplate := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/faq.html"))
    return indexTemplate, faqTemplate
}

func main() {
    var mux = http.NewServeMux()
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
    mux.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static", fs))
    indexTemplate, faqTemplate := initTemplates()
    ...
}
```

My problem with this is it seems strange to have a variable here like this for each page on my website. What if I want to have 100 pages? Additionally, how do I even pass these variables to my handling functions defined above?

---

**EDIT6:**

How about this?

`main.go`

```
var templates map[string]*template.Template

func init() {
    if templates == nil {
        templates = make(map[string]*template.Template)
    }

    templates["index.html"] = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/index.html"))
    templates["faq.html"] = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/faq.html"))
}

func main() {
    var mux = http.NewServeMux()
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
    mux.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static", fs))
    registerRoutes(mux)
    httpServer := http.Server{
        Addr:    ":3000",
        Handler: mux,
    }
    err := httpServer.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
}
```

Then in `handlers.go` I use `tmpl := templates["index.html"]`

---

**EDIT7:** Not sure if I should make a new question at this point but I'll just keep going.

I ran into a problem when trying to service the resource `/purchase/license`. Now the server is looking in `/purchase/static/stylesheets/main.css` on that page. How can I resolve this?

---

**EDIT8:** I resolved my previous edit by adding

```
mux.Handle("/purchase/static/", http.StripPrefix("/purchase/static", fs))
```

to `main()`. Is there a better, more scaleable way of resolving this? What if I have hundreds of `/x/y`, do I really need to add one of these for each `x`? Could I use regex or something to add a wildcard like this?

```
mux.Handle("*/static/", http.StripPrefix("*/static", fs))
```

If so, how would I do that exactly?

Comment: What do you mean? The template is doing everything it should be doing. The CSS and JS aren't part of the template, you just have tags that link to those files.

Comment: @hobbs Exactly my problem

Comment: You're missing a trailing slash: `mux.HandleFunc("/static/", ...)`. Also consider using [http.FileServer](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) instead of writing one yourself.

Comment: You should really follow what Peter has said: implement http.FileServer to serve the directory. You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17690230) on how to do that

Comment: @Peter I tried to implement this but I don't understand how to fit it in with my current structure. See my edit

Comment: @xarantolus As mentioned in my previous comment, I have tried this (as shown in my edit) but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You have to "serve" the JS and CSS files as well.

The template is rendered and sent as an HTML page. Once the HTML page is loaded, the browser tries to load the CSS and JS files using the links in the page. Since your server does not handle those routes, the browser cannot load them.

I suggest instead of using ../static path, use /static in the HTML, and mount that route to your router with a handler that loads the CSS and JS files and returns them. You also have to set the Content-Type of the response so the browser can use those files correctly.

```
// Register the handler
mux.HandleFunc("/static", staticHandler)


func staticHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   // load the file using r.URL.Path, like /static/scripts/index.js"
   data,err:=ioutil.ReadFile(...)
   // Figure out file type:
   if strings.EndsWith("js") {
      w.Header.Set("Content-Type","text/javascript")  
   } else {
      w.Header.Set("Content-Type","text/css")
   }
   w.Write(data)
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your edit, but I'm really quite new to Go (coming from Python, trying to replicate parts of Flask) so I have no idea how to implement that.

Comment: Okay so I think maybe I get part of it. I should include `data,err:=ioutil.ReadFile("/static/scripts/index.js")` and then set the headers. However, you have removed my code that executes my template.

Comment: Additionally, how do I do this if I want multiple files of different types? Say 1 CSS 1 JS as in my example.

Comment: My edits are an addition to your code, not a replacement. The code I added handles css and js based on the extension of the file.

Comment: Check my edit, I think that is the code you meant to right but it isn't working.

Comment: Run it through a debugger, or printf the path in the handler and see that the url path does not contain the localhost:port part.

Comment: Check the errors, run it through a debugger and see what fails. I can't debug it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Burak Serdar for the guidance, I fixed some of his code and added a few things to get a solution.

Added this to `handlers.go`

```
func staticHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   path := r.URL.Path
   if strings.HasSuffix(path, "js") {
      w.Header().Set("Content-Type","text/javascript")
   } else {
      w.Header().Set("Content-Type","text/css")
   }
   data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path[1:])
   if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
   _, err = w.Write(data)
   if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
   }
}
```

Added this to `routes.go`

```
mux.HandleFunc("/static/", staticHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. The key point is the router for the static handler, you need to ensure referencing the correct absolute path for the static file. Here it goes:

## dir structure

```
.
go.mod
go.sum
website/
├── main.go
└── static
    ├── css
    │   └── index.css
    ├── scripts
    │   └── index.js
    └── templates
        └── index.html
```

Go run:

```
go run ./website/
```

## main.go

```
var (
    staticDir    = getAbsDirPath() + "/static/"
    templatesDir = staticDir + "/templates"
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
        templatesDir + "/index.html",
    ))
)

func getAbsDirPath() string {
    pwd, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // my dir name is 'website'
    return pwd + "/website"
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", nil)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

func staticHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := r.URL.Path
    if strings.HasSuffix(path, "js") {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/javascript")
    } else {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/css")
    }
    // make sure you reference the correct absolute path
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(staticDir + path[1:])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    _, err = w.Write(data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    // <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
    // <script src="../scripts/index.js" defer></script>
    http.HandleFunc("/scripts/", staticHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/css/", staticHandler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil))
}
```

## homepage rendering

[image: index.html css rendering]
[image: index.html js rendering]

## static file details

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Index</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to Litong's homepage!</h1>

<script src="../scripts/index.js" defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

> index.js

```
let title = document.querySelector('h1')

title.onclick = function () {
  alert('Let\'s build a better world!')
}
```

> index.css

```
h1 {
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```